# Having more electrons than the Fermi energy allows

Tags: electrons, superconductivity, metals, fermi-energy

What happens when we have more electrons in a solid metal than the Fermi energy and Pauli exclusion allows?

Let's say we reduce the temperature to a level where all the energy states are filled with two electrons (up+down), including the Fermi level, then we either reduce the temperature more, or add more electrons, what happens then? does that make the metal super-conductor or does it just make a negative charge? what energy state additional electrons will occupy?

Comment: Why do you think that reducing the temperature would cause "all the energy states [to be] filled with two electrons." The energy states don't change with temperature, since the Hamiltonian doesn't change. The Fermi Energy *is* the chemical potential at zero temperature. This will be in the middle of a "band" for an idealized metal (I mean a metal where we "ignore" interactions, as usual).

Comment: There are plenty of free levels above the Fermi level. You may have the wrong idea about the meaning of Fermi level in metals.

Comment: My understanding is that the Fermi-Dirac distribution, shows the probability of finding an electron above the Fermi energy, which in the case of 0 degrees Kelvin, would be 0. but even at higher temperatures, appraches zero.

So I was wondering, what happens when we are at zero probability but have more electrons?

Comment: This [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDVS-VwwkKI) helped me understand that it is possible to have electrons even above the Fermi level where the probability is zero, but even if that's the case, how does that satisfy Pauli's exclusion principle? does that mean that some of the electrons ( those above band at 0 K ) occupy the same state as another fermion with the same exact propeties?